# Import csv file to mysql table fileds in homestead laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv, homestead

I am using homestead vagrant to store databases...Now i created table in my homestead as brands

```
mysql> desc brands;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am having huge data fro this table .Now i want to add fields for this table from excel saved in .csv format how i make this possible...

Comment: To add new fields use ALTER TABLE statement - [ALTER TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html). To load data from CSV-file use LOAD DATA INFILE command - [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found this code online somewhere years ago. It might need slight modification but the concept is there.

In your Database Seeder file, in the run() method:

```
// path to csv file
$csvFilename = app_path().'/../database/seeds/csv/filename.csv';

// run the seeder and get the variable to store the CSV data array
$seedData = $this->seedFromCSV($csvFilename, ',');

// Insert into your table
DB::table($csvTable)->insert($seedData);
```

Now in the seeder below, ensure your header names match the table names in the database.

```
/**
 * Collect data from a given CSV file and return as array
 *
 * @param $filename
 * @param string $deliminator
 * @return array|bool
 */
private function seedFromCSV($filename, $deliminator = ',')
{

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();

    if(($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while(($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $deliminator)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header) {
                $header = $row;
            } else {
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }

        }

        fclose($handle);
    }

    return $data;

}
```